# $unwind twice, how to get field from first unwind?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo query that has two unwinds to get an array of chapters. I need to get the story "slug" of the current chapter.  I tried having a "story.slug": 1 in the $project part, but that just returned me with an array of slugs that the user owns.

A mongo document looks like this:

```
{
    name: 'Test User',
    slug: 'test_user',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'test',
    story: [
    {
      title: 'Story Title',
      blurb: 'Epic story of a girl',
      slug: 'epic_story_of_a_girl', // Need this ....
      active: true,
      chapters: [{
        title: 'Story',
        chapter: '1',
        content: 'This is the story of a girl. Cried a river and drowned the whole world.',
        slug: '1',
      }]
}
```

My mongo query looks like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([

    {$project: {
         email: 1,
         name: 1,
         slug: 1,
         chapters: "$story.chapters"
     }}, 

    {$unwind: "$chapters"},
    {$unwind: "$chapters"}, 
    {$match: {"chapters.active": true}},
    {$sort: {"chapters._id": -1}},
    {$limit: 20}
])
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
         "name" : "Test User",
         "slug" : "test_user",
         "email" : "test@test.com",
         "chapters" : {
                 "title" : "Story",
                 "chapter" : "1",
                 "content" : "This is the story of a girl. Cried a river and drowned the whole world.",
                 "slug" : "1"
         }
 }
```

But i want the result to look like this or similar and i have no idea how.

```
{
         "name" : "Test User",
         "slug" : "test_user",
         "email" : "test@test.com",
         "storySlug": "epic_story_of_a_girl" // This thing
         "chapters" : {
                 "title" : "Story",
                 "chapter" : "1",
                 "content" : "This is the story of a girl. Cried a river and drowned the whole world.",
                 "slug" : "1"
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think your getting a little off track by what you did in the first projection phase. That's what seems to be tripping you up. Consider the following:

```
db.users.aggregate([

    // Try and put a $match phase in here to at least narrow down the items
    // Your later condition is valid even if we are going to get the whole arrays
    {$match: {"chapters.active": true}},

    // First you unwind the story array   
    {"$unwind": "$story"},

    // Then you unwind the chapters array within
    {"$unwind": "$story.chapters"},

    // Match again to "just" get only the active chapters
    {"$match": {"chapters.active": true}},

    // Project into your form
    {"$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": 1,
        "email": 1,
        "storySlug": "$story.slug",
        "activeChapter": "$story.chapters"
    }},         

    // Let's stop here so you can look
    {"$limit": 1}
 ])
```

Now that's all fine if you have **only** one *"active"* chapter at a time, but otherwise you will need to normalize with a group. Which is kind of interchangeable with the $project

```
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$name",
            "email": "$email",
            "storySlug": "$story.slug"
        },
        "chapters": {"$push": "$story.chapters" }
    }}
```

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: That worked rather well, didn't know you could have $project later down the pipeline. Just had to make some of the $match filters "story.chapters.active".